# Psychopy: Rescale all visual image objects at once

Tags: python, aspect-ratio, psychopy

I'm implementing an experiment in Psychopy 1.85.1.

The task will be administered on a 1920 x 1080 monitor (i.e. 16:9 aspect ratio).

Rather than change the size of each individual visual image object I use by the following:

```
some_obj.size *= [0.6,1]
```

I'd rather use a single line of code that just universally chances the size parameters of all the visual objects to account for the warping caused by being in a 16:9 ratio.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Below is an example of the stretch caused by psychopy's default to an 4:3 ratio and the appropriate image. Left is what occurs when the image size is unchanged, right is what occurs when the image size is altered as shown above.

[image]

The window for the experiment is created by:

```
myWin = visual.Window(size = (1200,675), fullscr = False,
                      winType = 'pyglet', color = 'white')
```

The circle images, as they appear above, and created by:

```
testCircleL = visual.Circle(myWin, fillColor = 'lightskyblue', lineColor = 'lightskyblue', units = 'norm',
                       radius = 0.5, pos=(-.50,0.15))
testCircleR = visual.Circle(myWin, fillColor = 'lightskyblue', lineColor = 'lightskyblue',
                       radius = 0.5, pos=(0.5,0.15)); testCircleR.size *= [0.6,1]
```

Comment: You may want to give more details. What size are the images now? Do they have to be full screen? You could just put up a colored background and lay them on top of it with their native size. Or you could use some other tool to scale and resize them for this screen. Imagemagick has worked well for me doing this. Show some code of how you do it now, and what is "wrong" about what happens.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I've edited the explanation above. The issue is specifically that whatever size you make the object in psychopy - it defaults to a 4:3 aspect ratio and when creating a window with a different aspect ratio, the images all need to be scaled. I can scale them one by one but would rather be able to have it just happen at once.

Comment: PsychoPy doesn't really default to a 4:3 aspect ratio. It sounds like you are using `norm` units, which are proportional to both dimensions of your screen (i.e. width = 2, height = 2). To make your stimuli portable across different window aspect ratios, use units = `height` instead. http://www.psychopy.org/general/units.html

Answer (score 3):

As Mike pointed out in the comments, If maintaining the aspect ratio is the issue, use `height`, `pix` (pixels), or `deg` as [units in the window](http://www.psychopy.org/general/units.html), e.g., `myWin = visual.Window(units='pix')`. Notice that for `deg`, you have to enter some distance measures in the Monitor Centre for it to work. Also, notice that you will have to rescale the numbers in your script. For example, a radius of 0.5 "norms" is big while a radius of 0.5 pixels barely covers one pixel.

If you really wanted to scale many stimuli at once, you would probably do it in a loop:

```
# Set up many visual objects
stim1 = visual.Circle(myWin)
stim2 = visual.ImageStim(myWin)
stim3 = visual.GratingStim(myWin)

# Scale multiple visual objects
for this_stim in [stim1, stim2, stim3]:
    this_stim.size *= [0.6, 1]
```

Of course, this only works for stimuli with a `size` attribute.